# My only connection string is LocalSqlServer - Why is Web.config not loading when I run a test?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, connection-string

I started an ASP.NET Web Application project in Visual Studio Community 2013 from the Empty template and ticked the Web API checkbox. I've installed SQL Server 2014 Express separately, and I've connected to my database under Server Explorer. Not sure if any of that's relevant.

I'm trying to open a connection to my database using a connection string in Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="DbConnection" connectionString="..."/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I've attempted to access it a couple ways:

```
var connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"].ToString();

var connStr = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

When I run a UnitTest, Everything I try pukes out a NullReferenceException.

Taking a look at what's in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings, all I find is machine.config's LocalSqlServer:

[image]

Why does it seem like Web.config isn't loading when I'm testing?

Comment: Is the `web.config` at the root of your site?

Comment: How are you running the project? Just hitting start with debugging button in VS?

Comment: @mason I was running a test... Looks like it works when I hit Start. Edited question to include that.

Comment: A unit test? As in, a separate project with its own `app.config`?

Comment: @mason Yes, a unit test. It has no app.config though.

Comment: why don't you mock the config?

Comment: Add an `app.config`. Contents can be the same as the `web.config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Don't use `.ToString()`. Use the `.ConnectionString` property. In addition, your `web.config` should be at the root of your site.

---

Unit Tests have their own separate configuration. You need an `app.config` file, though the contents can be the same as you posted in your question.